# Debugging Code in Visual Studio 2017 with a Barcode Scanner: Can I set editor buffer read-only somehow?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to debug some code that is using USB HID devices (barcode scanners). To test the code, I have to scan barcodes.  Most barcode devices these days are HID-class compliant USB devices.  To Windows, they appear as keyboards, which is great for making them instantly compatible with windows software.

The trouble is when developers using visual Studio are debugging code that is receiving streams of HID class (keyboard) key press data via the Windows Raw HID Input APIs.

When breakpoints are hit, and the IDE pops up and then the barcode scanner CONTINUOUS it's continous send of key up and key down and key press events, which then causes accidental input of bar-code scanner's output text into my code (.c and .cpp) files.

On some IDEs you can set the IDE read only during debug so that you have to switch back to edit mode (end debugging) to edit. This would be hugely useful for some users and for some scenarios but appears to be impossible in visual studio.

Some IDE features around this would be lost if Editing could be disabled, for example, you would be losing edit and continue features. But as I don't need those features, and would prefer to not have my code be damaged by my barcode scanner activity, having a read only debugger would be useful.

I am thinking that an IDE Extension that lets me right click and at least mark certain editor buffers as read-only would be useful.  If I figure out how to do that at least, I will update and answer my own question.

In other IDEs there are ways to make the IDE set all editor buffers read-only while debugging, so that keys you hit while using the application under test, or in my case, the barrage of key presses coming from a barcode scanner, do not damage your source code.

Currently I have to use the editor undo function to recover from this, or I have to set the file to read-only on disk, to prevent this, is there not any way to do this from the IDE?  (Other IDEs do have this feature)

Or an IDE Plugin that will set focus to some other window than my code, when the IDE pops up at a breakpoint?

Comment: Hi, do you use the `attach to process` to debug the app? Do you mean every time you scan barcodes, it will send text to your source file itself? Or you mean it sends something like a string to your code, but not modify your xx.cpp file itself?

Comment: I mean I am debugging barcode handling code, and a breakpoint may be hit, and the keyboard "buffer" (really the USB HID processing pipeline in windows itself) continues to spill noise from the HID traffic into my code under test.

If I do not use visual studio and do not use breakpoints, or I am not debugging code which is basically "pressing keys on the key board", visual studio's behaviour is not annoying.

But if you do have to debug code that is processing, say raw USB keyboard layer APIs in Windows, this becomes very annoying.

Comment: Sorry that I have no valid idea for this,  I don't find any option in Tools=>Options can control this behavior, maybe you can post it as a feature request to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).